# Running an apache2 website and I can't get my uploading program to work

Tags: php, html, networking, apache2

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/var/www/html/MAD/upload/uploads/Screenshot 2023-04-28 at 10.00.49 PM.png): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/MAD/upload/uploader.php on line 22
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move "/tmp/phpJUBHJx" to "/var/www/html/MAD/upload/uploads/Screenshot 2023-04-28 at 10.00.49 PM.png" in /var/www/html/MAD/upload/uploader.php on line 22
Error uploading file move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move "/tmp/phpJUBHJx" to\<!DOCTYPE html\>
```

I put the script and directory in a group and gave them both read and write access. I also messed around in the apache2.conf file to see if there is a permission I am missing. I have installed the php module and enabled it, I just can't figure out what is going on with the permissions since the script and has read write and the directory has all permissions. I have tried it with the script having execute permissions as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
  <title> PHP File Upload </title> 
</head> 
  
<body> 
        <h1>File Upload Form</h1> 
  
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
  
  
/*Get name of the uploaded file and verify it uploaded*/ 
  
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name']; 
  
/* Set the location to save the file */ 
$location = __dir__."/uploads/".$filename; 
/* Save the uploaded file to the local filesystem */ 
if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $location)){ 
        echo 'File uploaded successfully'; 
}else{ 
        $error = error_get_last(); 
        if ($error !== null) { 
                echo 'Error uploading file ' . $error['message'] . '. Error code: ' . $_FILES['file']['error']; 
        } 
} 
  
?> 
  
  
  
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
  <input type="file" id="file" name="file" /> 
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload" /> 
</form> 
  
</body> 
</html>
```